# Change mime type based on url parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to set the mime type based on url because it's being transferred as text/html instead of text/css.

When url has the parameter `pjActionLoadCss` is should be transferred as text/css.

I using the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=pjActionLoadCss
```

For eg:. https://example.com/something/index.php?controller=pjFront&action=pjActionLoadCss

How can i write RewriteRule to transfer as css?
I'm trying to set with without success [T=text/css].

Comment: Actually the correct mime type header should be set by the controller, not by a _guessing_ protocol layer.

Comment: Header is already being set in controller but for some reason only this url is not being transferred as css. Theres another pjActionLoadCss with same contents and same function which is being transferred as css.

Comment: If that _really_ is the case, that your controller explicitly sends a mime type header, then the obvious task to do is find out why it does not work for that specific case, since headers do not simply vanish into plain air. You should fix the cause, but you are trying to cure the symptom!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i did in htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=pjActionLoadCss
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=is_css:true]

Header set Content-Type text/css env=is_css
```